# Relational Algebra/Set Theory: Why when selecting in a "self-join" is the data not ordered

Tags: algorithms, relation-algebra

I hope I'm asking in the right place. I don't think this is appropriate for stackoverflow.

In Microsoft Sql Server (MSSQL) and Oracle SQL (T-SQL), if you perform the following query:

select a.*,b.* 
from A as [a], A as [b]

On the following data in set A:

ID,Value

1,a

2,b

3,c

4,d

5,e

The result set will be

A.id,A.value,B.id,B.value

1,a,1,a

2,b,1,a

3,c,1,a

4,d,1,a

5,e,1,a

1,a,2,b

2,b,2,b

3,c,2,b

4,d,2,b

...

Why was this order chosen and defined for an unrestricted self-join? I guess, my question is - is this result the same between Oracle and Microsoft because the result is rooted in relational algebra/set theory somewhere, which is rooted in some mathematical principle? If so, where can I learn more about this?

Or, is there no mathematical reason for this ordering and it's purely coincidence based on language implementation / performance?

My initial assumption when running into this was that it would automatically be ordered like this:

1,a,1,a

1,a,1,a

1,a,1,a

1,a,1,a

1,a,1,a

2,b,2,b

2,b,2,b

2,b,2,b

2,b,2,b

2,b,2,b

Comment: The ordering was simply an implementation choice. It would be called the "right-to-left dictionary order". Why they have it right-to-left, I don't understand. I would expect it to be the other around (1a1b,  1a2b,  1a3b, etc). I'm no SQL expert, but the joins I've seen have been in dictionary order (i.e., left-to-right). Your assumption makes no sense. That is not even a join, which should match every element of the first with every element of the second, not with one element of the second over and over again for no apparent reason.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.